# get values from another table on a trigger

Tags: oracle

So, i am a begginer on ORACLE and realy would apreciate your help.

I have 3 tables, EMPLOEES, PERSONAL_DATA and RECORDS. I want to create an UPDATE TRIGGER that when  fires takes the old values of EMPLOOES finds the personal data of that updating emplooe on the PERSONAL_DATA table with the OLD id and insert all of that data( the OLD of EMPLOOES and the one fetched from PERSONAL_DATA) into the RECORDS table. I been triying to use the SELECT sentence to fetch information from the table PERSONAL_DATA, but the compiler throws me an error.

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the SQL being used.

Comment: Also, please show us the schema, the trigger and the error message that you encounter. Thanks